# How to protect the expansion of exponent while applyting rules

Tags: list-manipulation, simplifying-expressions, replacement, polynomials

I am trying to separate/split an expression (consisting of polynomials) to a list. However I want to keep the exponents intact.  Here is an example:

```
k1=((x+y)^(2+e) (a+b)^(-1-e) (k - z) )//Expand
k2=k1 /. Times | Plus  | Power -> List
```

output:

```
(a + b)^(-1 - e) k (x + y)^(2 + e) - (a + b)^(-1 - e) (x + y)^(2 + e) z
{{{{a, b}, {-1, {-1, e}}}, k, {{x, y}, {2, e}}}, {-1, {{a, b}, {-1, {-1, e}}}, {{x, y}, {2, e}}, z}}
```

The problem in this approach is it makes list in which it is not apparant to distinguish `-e` and `-1+e` .

```
 -e /. Times | Plus | Power -> List
 -1+e /. Times | Plus | Power -> List
```

leads to same `{-1, e}`. For each `-` sign it creates a list which is unwanted.

In this example,

**How do I prevent applying `Plus -> List` to the exponent?**

The reason is I want to finally get back to the following form from each term of the list at the end, i.e.

```
k2[[1]], k2[[2]] etc.
```

where

```
 k2[[1]][[1]] = (a + b)^(-1 - e) 
 k2[[1]][[2]] = (x + y)^(2 + e)
 k2[[1]][[3]] = k

 k2[[2]][[1]] = (a + b)^(-1 - e) 
 k2[[2]][[2]] = (x + y)^(2 + e) 
 k2[[2]][[3]] = -z
```

EDIT::

The expected final output

```
 k2={
 {{(a + b),(-1 - e)},{ k },{(x + y),(2 + e)}},
 {{(a + b),(-1 - e)},{-z},{(x + y),(2 + e)}}
    }
```

or

```
  k2={
  {{{a , b},{-1, - e}},{ k },{{x , y},{2 , e}}},
  {{{a , b},{-1, - e}},{-z},{{x , y},{2 , e}}}
     }
```

Such that finally I get each of the two terms ( which are separated by `+/-`)

```
  (1.)   (a + b)^(-1 - e) k (x + y)^(2 + e) 
  (2.) - (a + b)^(-1 - e) (x + y)^(2 + e) z
```

Also from `(1.)` and `(2.)` I will get each terms which are multiplied i.e.

```
  (1.)  (a + b)^(-1 - e),  k,  (x + y)^(2 + e)
  (2.)  (a + b)^(-1 - e), -z, (x + y)^(2 + e)
```

I find the difficult part is to handle this `-`ve sign.

Comment: does `k1 /. {Power[a_, b_] :> Power[a /. Plus | Times -> List, b] ,  Plus | Times -> List}` give what you need?

Comment: partially,(I can work on this) since my final goal is to first separate out each terms first by `+-` and then for each of them I want to find out the terms which are multiplied. Like in this example first `k2 = k2[[1]] + k2[[2]]`. Then for each `k2[[i]]` I want to take out each term which is multipled. Like from k2[[1]] I want `(a + b)^(-1 - e)`, `(x + y)^(2 + e)`, `k`.

Comment: can you post the desired output for `k2`? and for `-e /.  rule1` and
`-1+e  /. rule2`?

Comment: @kglr, pls see update. I can infact take the above comment of yours and make it work to get the desired output by just simple final substitution: `k2[[1]][[1]] /. {{x_^y_, a_^b_} -> (x+a)^y}`.

Comment: The  problem comes in handling `-` ve sign in a general case. In your scond list `k2[[2]]`, it contains `-1` as one of the list element, which I like to keep with any of the terms. I can probably do a workaround. Basically the top level lists will have same `Length`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ReplaceAll[Power -> List] @ Replace[SortBy[Length] /@ (List @@@ List @@ k1), 
   {a_, b_, c___} :> If[a === -1, {{-b}, c}, {{a}, b, c}], 2]
```

> ```
> {{{k}, {a + b, -1 - e}, {x + y, 2 + e}}, 
>  {{-z}, {a + b, -1 - e}, {x + y, 2 + e}}}
> ```

Use  `ReplaceAll[Power | Plus -> List]` to get

> ```
> {{{k}, {{a, b}, {-1, -e}}, {{x, y}, {2, e}}},
>  {{-z}, {{a, b}, {-1, -e}}, {{x, y}, {2, e}}}}
> ```